# MySql Connector - A non-blocking socket operation @ nonQuery

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a mysql inserting program that is set to run after another program is complete...

The way I do this is that the last thing the inital program does is to start the mysql inserting program... Here is the method

```
  ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = "PFML_STATES_MYSQL.exe";
           startInfo.Arguments = args[0];
            Process.Start(startInfo);
            Environment.Exit(0);
```

I am currently getting a stacktrace from this block of code within the mysql inserter

```
public void ClearAll(string args)
        {
            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = this.connection;
                if (args.Equals("ny"))
                    command.CommandText = "delete from jurisdiction where offender_id  IN (select offender_id from offenders WHERE offender_id like 'NY%' AND risk_level !=1);delete from offenders_locations where offender_id  IN (select offender_id from offenders WHERE offender_id like 'NY%' AND risk_level !=1);delete from vehicles where offenders_id  IN (select offender_id from offenders WHERE offender_id like 'NY%' AND risk_level !=1);delete from alias where offenders_id  IN (select offender_id from offenders WHERE offender_id like 'NY%' AND risk_level !=1);delete from marks where offenders_id  IN (select offender_id from offenders WHERE offender_id like 'NY%' AND risk_level !=1);delete from offender_pictures where offenders_id  IN (select offender_id from offenders WHERE offender_id like 'NY%' AND risk_level !=1);delete from sentencing_info where offenders_id  IN (select offender_id from offenders WHERE offender_id like 'NY%' AND risk_level !=1);delete from crimes where offendersXREF  IN (select offender_id from offenders WHERE offender_id like 'NY%' AND risk_level !=1);delete from offender_pictures_additional where offenders_id IN (select offender_id from offenders WHERE offender_id like 'NY%' AND risk_level !=1);";
                else
                {
                    command.CommandText = "delete from jurisdiction where offender_id  IN (select offender_id from offenders WHERE offender_id like 'NY%' AND risk_level !=1 and (county_id = 360052 or county_id = 360099 or county_id = 360030));delete from offenders_locations where offender_id  IN (select offender_id from offenders WHERE offender_id like 'NY%' AND risk_level !=1 and (county_id = 360052 or county_id = 360099 or county_id = 360030));delete from vehicles where offenders_id  IN (select offender_id from offenders WHERE offender_id like 'NY%' AND risk_level !=1 and (county_id = 360052 or county_id = 360099 or county_id = 360030));delete from alias where offenders_id  IN (select offender_id from offenders WHERE offender_id like 'NY%' AND risk_level !=1 and (county_id = 360052 or county_id = 360099 or county_id = 360030));delete from marks where offenders_id  IN (select offender_id from offenders WHERE offender_id like 'NY%' AND risk_level !=1 and (county_id = 360052 or county_id = 360099 or county_id = 360030));delete from offender_pictures where offenders_id  IN (select offender_id from offenders WHERE offender_id like 'NY%' AND risk_level !=1 and (county_id = 360052 or county_id = 360099 or county_id = 360030));delete from sentencing_info where offenders_id  IN (select offender_id from offenders WHERE offender_id like 'NY%' AND risk_level !=1 and (county_id = 360052 or county_id = 360099 or county_id = 360030));delete from crimes where offendersXREF  IN (select offender_id from offenders WHERE offender_id like 'NY%' AND risk_level !=1 and (county_id = 360052 or county_id = 360099 or county_id = 360030));delete from offender_pictures_additional where offenders_id IN (select offender_id from offenders WHERE offender_id like 'NY%' AND (county_id = 360052 or county_id = 360099 or county_id = 360030) AND risk_level !=1);";
                }
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

The stacktrace, which i deleted because I am silly... But it said something like A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately from command.executereader() > command.executenonquery()

The really funny part about this problem is it ONLY happens when the inital program starts the mysql inserter, if I MANUALLY start the inserter it runs perfectly...

Error:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Fatal error encountered during
>   command execution. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Fatal
>   error encountered attempting to read the resultset. --->
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Reading from the stream has
>   failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the
>   transport connection: A non-blocking socket operation could not be
>   completed immediately. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A
>   non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a good answer for this as the issue wasn't persistent...

But I restarted the server twice and it fixed it self.